# Минимальное ненулевое значение из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как вывести минимальное ненулевое значение из массива.

```
echo min(1, 2, 3, 100 , 0, 4);
```

Будет "0", подскажите, как исключить нули

Answer (score 4):

Вам просто необходимо отфильтровать массив перед передачей его методу min().

```
$input = array(12,3,45,30,0,3,0);
$output = array_filter($input, function($elem) {
    return $elem !== 0;
});
echo min($output);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но меня спасла такая самописка:

function min_not_null(Array $values) {
    return min(array_diff(array_map('intval', $values), array(0)));
}

Comment: Очень нехорошая самописка). Вы либо закройте вопрос, либо отметьте понравившийся вам ответ как правильный.

Comment: @Ridzhi, что Ваше решение, что решение ТС - оба слетят, если все элементы входного массива нулевые. А в остальном, решение через `array_diff` намного симпатичнее.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, есть ли какой-то более простой способ, но, по-моему, тут только делать проверку:

```
 $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 100 , 0, 4);
 $val = sort($arr);
 for ($i;$<count($val);$i++)
 {
    if $val[$i]!=0
    {
      $result = $val[$i];
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Что то вы намудрили...

Comment: Блин, действительно хрень написал. Хоть на говнокод отправляй. .__.

Answer (score 0):

С использованием [map_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php). Если значений > 0 нет - вернет NULL, но можно значение для такого случая переопределить - указать его третьим параметром для ф-ции *array_reduce()*

```
<?php
echo array_reduce(
    [1, 2, 3, 100 , 0, 4],
    function ($carry, $item) {
        return $item !== 0 && ($carry === null || $carry > $item)? $item: $carry;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$min = min(array_filter($input));
```